# Rails check if params exist in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a `factor` controller which takes factor values for two different types of factors

1. Primary Factor
2. Secondary Factor

And I pass them as params as follows:

```
class FactorController < AdminController

  def create
    if primary_factor_params                              ## LINE 5
      do something
    elsif secondary_factor_params
      do something else
    end
  end

  def primary_factor_params
    params.require(:primary).permit(:user_id,            ## LINE 70
                                           :primary_factors)
  end

  def secondary_factor_params
    params.require(:secondary).permit(:user_id,
                                        :secondary_factors)
  end
end
```

But in the above whenever I try to pass a `secondary_factor` I get the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: primary):
  app/controllers/factors_controller.rb:70:in `primary_factor_params'  app/controllers/api/v1/admin/factors_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

So to me it seems that this error is coming up because I didn't have any values for `primary_factor_params` in this condition and that's way it throws the error because of the first if condition.

I've tried:

```
primary_factor_params.exists?
primary_factor_params.has_key?(:primary_factors)
....
```

But all of them throw the same error since `primary_factor_params` doesn't exist. Is there a way to test this without throwing an error for missing params?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line `params.require(:primary)` saying that the parameter is required, so attempting to do like `params.require(:primary).exists?` wont help you if you do not have a `:primary` param at all because the `require` already failed.

You need to check its existance on `params` itself. For example `params.has_key?(:primary)`.

Dependening on your use case, you might also use `params.permit(:primary)` directly on `params` as well. See the API docs for detailed information on how `ActionController::Parameters` (the class for `params`) can be used.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense, I blanked out on the fact that I need to test on `params` because `primary_factor_params` wouldn't exist in this case at all

Comment: @Fire Lancer thank you! I just ran into a situation where I had to conditionally set a base variable to look up associated records using different relationships depending on the model requesting the associated records and this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

you can check your params existence in your case by `params[:primary].present?`
I think this is the easiest way